# Which is the best MAPI or Exchange web service to access the data from exchange server 2010 data store?

Tags: exchange-server, mapi

I am going to develop a client application in C++ to access user availability and calander information from Excahnge server 2010. Which is the best to use MAPI or Exchange web service to develop client application in C++ to access user availability and calander information from Excahnge server 2010?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MAPI, but it will probably much harder than using EWS (though I don't know how hard it is to call WebServices from C++ - never done that).

Another way is to use Redemption (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm), a COM MAPI Abstraction Layer.